# Can I copy files to Amazon EC2 without a PEM file (using AWS CLI)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I used to use the below scp command to copy files from my local machine to instances earlier.

`scp -i /path/to/pem/file /path/to/source user@ip-address:/path/to/destination`

But for a new instance, I do not have access to the PEM file. We are using AWS CLI to manage access to new instances and hence, there is no need for a PEM file. Is there a way to copy files using AWS CLI as well?

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 (if that helps)

Comment: You can try using FileZilla

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what to use?

Comment: @RumjhumSingru if I'm not wrong, FileZilla requires me to have the PEM file right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got some help and found that there are three steps to this process.

1. Start a secure FTP connection with the instance using the following command:
   `msftp <user>@<instance_id>`
2. Use 'put' to copy your files to the instance using:
   `put /path/to/source /path/to/destination`
3. `exit`

Similarly, use get instead of put to copy files from the instance to your local machine. Remember to use the -r flag if you're copying directories!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/session-manager-launches-tunneling-support-for-ssh-and-scp/) to copy files using scp:

> With SSH protocol tunneling using Session Manager, you do not need an access server or an open inbound port for SSH-based access and **SCP-based file copy**. This reduces cost and improves your security posture when using SSH and SCP.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm interpreting you right, but do you mean that I have to login to the AWS Systems Manager portal to copy files? Is there no direct command-line tool?

Comment: @AmanMohandas this can be used from command line too. For more info you can go through [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/what-is-systems-manager.html)

Answer (score 0):

AWS Session Manager allows you to connect to an EC2 instance without having an ssh setup (no keypair, no ssh port to open). Hence you can't use `scp`.

As workaround, you can **use an S3 bucket as proxy**.
You can upload from your local to S3 and then, from your Session Manager, download from the S3 using aws cli.

For this you should provide permissions to your EC2 to access your S3.

[All steps explained here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/)

Comment: That's not true, using SCP is possible using SSM as explained in the official documentation.
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/session-manager-launches-tunneling-support-for-ssh-and-scp/